# Logstash expecting \n for it to process an XML

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am trying to parse through an XML file and read only a single tag out of the entire XML using the Grok Patterns.

My grok pattern looks like this. Its able to parse through an XML when its properly indented, as there's a new line after each closing tag. But when the file comes with no spaces in between consecutive tags, this pattern does not work. Could anyone help here?

```
 input {
      beats {
        port => 5045
        type => 'iis'
      }

    }    
    filter {
        #ignore log comments
        if [message] =~ "^#" {
        drop {}
        }

        grok {
        patterns_dir => "./patterns"
        match => ["message", "%{DATA:extras}<LoadID%{DATA:extra}>%{DATA:ASNNumber}%{GREEDYDATA:behind}"]
        }
        date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        locale => "en"
        }
        }

        Second filter
        filter {
        if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
        drop { }
        } else {
        # on success remove the message field to save space
        mutate {
        remove_field => ["message", "timestamp", "extra", "extras", "behind"]
        }
        }
        }
```

This fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?><tns:ASNAck xmlns:tns='http://www.xyx.com/YYY/logistics/mxg/xnsds/V1_0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><MessageHeader><MessageID>3031999515</MessageID><MessageTimeStamp>2017-09-12T06:37:36Z</MessageTimeStamp><SenderID>XBHSNS</SenderID><ReceiverID>GOLF_DAO</ReceiverID><MessageType>ACKACKACK</MessageType><CorrelationID>2d323537383935353034383933383135</CorrelationID></MessageHeader><Masterbill>G829441</Masterbill><LoadID>Jitesh555</LoadID><Accept>true</Accept><ReasonCode/><ReasonDescription/></tns:ASNAck>
```

**This works:**

```
<tns:ASNAck xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.xyx.com/YYY/logistics/mxg/xnsds/V1_0">
    <MessageHeader>
        <MessageID>20170704080189</MessageID>
        <MessageTimeStamp>2017-07-04T20:17:30Z</MessageTimeStamp>
        <SenderID>KNN_DAO_MXC</SenderID>
        <ReceiverID>GOLF_DAO</ReceiverID>
        <MessageType>InboundASNAck</MessageType>
        <CorrelationID>2d383736363033383337333530313338</CorrelationID>
    </MessageHeader>
    <MasterWaybill>C211</MasterWaybill>
    <LoadID>10112275912A02</LoadID>
    <Accept>true</Accept>
    <ReasonCode>0</ReasonCode>
    <ReasonDescription/>
</tns:ASNAck>
```

**This works too:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?><tns:ASNAck xmlns:tns='http://www.xyx.com/YYY/logistics/mxg/xnsds/V1_0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><MessageHeader><MessageID>3031999515</MessageID><MessageTimeStamp>2017-09-12T06:37:36Z</MessageTimeStamp><SenderID>XBHSNS</SenderID><ReceiverID>GOLF_DAO</ReceiverID><MessageType>ACKACKACK</MessageType><CorrelationID>2d323537383935353034383933383135</CorrelationID></MessageHeader><Masterbill>G829441</Masterbill><LoadID>Jitesh555</LoadID>
<Accept>true</Accept><ReasonCode/><ReasonDescription/></tns:ASNAck>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse the whole string, you can just grab the part that interest you.

```
 grok {
    patterns_dir => "./patterns"
    match => ["message", "<LoadID>%{GREEDYDATA:ASNNumber}</LoadID>"]
 }
```

I also dropped the "extra", "extras", "behind" fields since you don't keep them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I started with this only. But this doesn't work. Its the same issue still. Logstash is expecting a new line after </LoadID>

Comment: Could you explain _what_ does not work? i. e. for example desired output vs current output, error messages/logs from logstash...

Comment: As i pointed out in the post. One file gets read and displays in Kibana while the other one does not

Comment: I can do nothing more with the information you provided. In Kibana, the display is (usually) dependent of the timestamp of the object in elasticsearch, perhaps that's why you can't see some of your object.